# Apple Push Notifications: Which server side library to use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apple-push-notifications

I'm using Dotnet web application (C#) to serve the requests coming from the native app. I'm thinking to use [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) for sending notification to an iOS device. But I'm not sure if it is the best. Is there any better alternative to this. If so, can You gimme some insight on them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use urbanairship to send push notifications to the device